# Getting the maximum of multiple sums

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I recently started learning to use neo4j with cypher, and I've encountered a task I just can't simply work out how to do.

This is how the relevant data I am working with looks:
[image]

Where the 'COOKS' relationship contains a property called 'popularity' that is simply a number of how 'popular' a cake is, and each cake is 'cooked' by a chef (The purple names).

My end goal is to return the node of the chef that has the most popular dishes, which in my case is achieved by summing all the 'popularity' properties in the relationships associated to anyone chef, and getting the maximum value out of all the sums. So far my best attempt was this:

```
match (chef:Chef)-[r:COOKS]->(c:Cake) return sum(r.popularity), chef
```

and the table result looks like this for me:

[image]

So now I just need to get the maximum value of all those sums, and return just the node(s) of the chefs that have this maximum sum of 'popularity'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slight variation on Dave Bennet's solution, instead of collecting each chef with their popularity, we can collect the chefs *by* their popularity (so for each row we'll have the popularity, and then collection of chefs with that specific popularity), then order these and take the row with all the chefs with the highest distinct popularity. This should let you handle ties.

```
MATCH (chef:Chef)-[r:COOKS]->(c:Cake) 
WITH chef, sum(r.popularity) AS popularity
WITH popularity, collect(chef) as chefs
ORDER BY popularity DESC
LIMIT 1
UNWIND chefs AS chef
RETURN chef, popularity
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for when returning multiple maximums (Identical ones) so thank you! While the other answer had a simple query for returning a single maximum, I'll mark yours as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

You can just take your query, sort the results in descending order and limit the return to the first row.

```
MATCH (chef:Chef)-[r:COOKS]->(c:Cake) 
RETURN chef, sum(r.popularity) AS popularity
ORDER BY popularity DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That will only get you a single chef though. In your sample I assume you would like both Bob and John returned.

In this case, perform the same search and order it in descending order but collect the results for each chef is in an ordered list from most popular to least popular. Then only return the rows of the list that match the most popular chefs.

```
MATCH (chef:Chef)-[r:COOKS]->(c:Cake) 
WITH chef, sum(r.popularity) AS popularity
ORDER BY popularity DESC
WITH COLLECT ([chef, popularity]) AS chefs
UNWIND chefs AS chef
WITH chef
WHERE chef[1] = chefs[0][1]
RETURN chef
```

Comment: The first solution does indeed work perfectly for when you're just returning one result, thank you! However your second one had errors, first was this: Invalid input 'O': expected 'r/R' or 'a/A' (line 4, column 2 (offset: 108))
and I assumed you meant WITH COLLECT(....) and I added the 'WITH' keyword, but then the error was: Expected Long(1) to be a org.neo4j.values.storable.TextValue, but it was a org.neo4j.values.storable.LongValue

So I've no idea how to get your second query working.

Comment: sorry - missed a `WITH`

Comment: I hit return too early sorry about that, I made an edit to the last comment about the 'with' keyword.

Comment: Also my mistake - i missed an "s" in `chefs[0][1]`. While my solution works and I think illustrates how to approach the problem, InverseFalcon's is a much tidier variation.